# Is it acceptable to flag old off topic questions?

Tags: discussion

On the main page I came across this question from 2013 which has recently been classed as 'active' (someone modified their original 2013 answer).
[Which is the better lens: Canon 28-105 or 28-135?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34937/which-is-the-better-lens-canon-28-105-or-28-135)

If this same question was posted today I expect this question would be pretty quickly flagged as off topic due to the 'which ones better A or B for a bit of everything' and the answer being only you can answer that.

So the real question is it ok to flag old questions to meet current standards or should they be left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine to action by current standards as it should be closed as no longer being a good fit.  It isn't like the information goes away, it'll just show that it isn't a good fit when people see it.